# C programming how to set fill to printf?

Tags: c, printf

In the C programming language, I can specify spaces before the arguments to print out columns.

```
printf("%10i", 50);
```

How can I set the fill to be underscores or dashes instead?

```
________50
```

Comment: There is no standard way to do what you would like to do.  You could format into a string, then modify the string, then print the modified string, but there isn't a standard built-in way to do it.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/VYqrPi)